# Is it possible to synchronize only terminal methods calls in java streams?

Tags: java, multithreading, java-stream

Let's consider the collection which could be accessed from differend threads. I'm looking for a thread-safe way to manipulate the collection using java streams.

Since all intermediate stream operations are lazy, real job would be executed only in terminal method. And i could synchronize only terminal method call.

So, is tha code thread-safe or not:

```
public void print(Collection<String> list){
      Stream stream = list.stream();
      synchronized(this){
          stream.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p)); 
      }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it depends on your application whether a `synchronized(this)` is sufficient (or necessary at all), to preclude manipulations to the source Collection during the Stream traversal.

Regarding the laziness, the exact behavior depends on the source Collection. Consider [the contract of `Collection.spliterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#spliterator--):

> In order to preserve expected laziness behavior for the `stream()` and `parallelStream()` methods, spliterators should either have the characteristic of `IMMUTABLE` or `CONCURRENT`, or be *late-binding*. If none of these is practical, the overriding class should describe the spliterator's documented policy of binding and structural interference, and should override the `stream()` and `parallelStream()` methods to create streams using a Supplier of the spliterator, as in:
>
> ```
> Stream<E> s = StreamSupport.stream(() -> spliterator(), spliteratorCharacteristics)
> ```
>
> These requirements ensure that streams produced by the `stream()` and `parallelStream()` methods will reflect the contents of the collection as of initiation of the terminal stream operation.

To shorten this, all of the variants listed above imply that modifications to the source Collection before commencing the terminal operation are permitted (of course, excluding `IMMUTABLE` spliterators) and will be reflected by the Stream operation.

So *if* your application guards all manipulations to the source list in a way that prevents manipulations to the source list while the terminal operation is executed, you’re on the safe side. But note that a method that receives a list as *parameter*, but synchronizes on `this` doesn’t look like guarding the list correctly. Just to make it clear: all threads must synchronize *on the same object* to protect a particular shared resource.

But letting this aside, assuming that all threads manipulating `list` will synchronize on `listLock` correctly, the following code would work:

```
Stream stream = list.stream()
    .intermediateOp1(…)
    .intermediateOp2(…);

synchronized(listLock){
    stream.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p)); 
}
```

but it would be pointless. As you stated yourself, the reason, why this works, is that chaining intermediate operations to the stream doesn’t cause any actual processing. It’s a very cheap thing, so excluding it from the guarded code section only implies that the time, the lock is held, might differ by a few nanoseconds.

You will hardly ever notice a difference to

```
synchronized(listLock) {
    list.stream()
        .intermediateOp1(…)
        .intermediateOp2(…)
        .forEach(p -> System.out.println(p)); 
}
```

as most of the time is spent within `forEach` anyway.

Comment: I had to delete my answer in favor of this, it's great. Still, it's sort of confusing hearing that most of the time is spent in the terminal operation. Indeed all the intermediate operations will be fused into a single one (one single Sink: AbstractPipeline#wrapSink), but that does not mean that all the work will be done in the terminal operation.

Comment: @Eugene: It’s important in this context, that the entire operation starts when `forEach` will be called and has completed, when `forEach` returns. This answer doesn’t say that `forEach` won’t call other methods during the process. But in terms of the method invocations of the shown code fragments, the time is spent almost entirely within `forEach` only. It might be counter-intuitive that the *functions* you pass to the stream via intermediate ops are lexically placed outside of `forEach`, but evaluated within `forEach`, so syncing the intermediate ops would have no effect to them.

Comment: either my words are misplaced or you meant something else. Imagine that the intermediateOp1 is a "map", that is pretty expensive, while the terminal forEach is much cheaper time-wise.  All I'm trying to stress out here is that terminal operation is not the only operation that takes the entire burden on it. *It really depends*.

Comment: @Eugene: Not the `map` method invocation is expensive, only the *function* argument to it might bear an expensive operation. But that function is never evaluated during the invocation of `map`. That operation will only be executed, while the terminal operation’s method like `forEach` is executed. Since this question is only about synchronizing these particular method invocations, i.e. `map` and `forEach`, only that matters here. *Conceptionally*, the mapping step (operation) costs CPU time, *technically*, everything happens with the `forEach` (invocation).

Comment: damn! I like a lot the word choosing here, that's like what I wanted to say but could not spell that out. I clearly see your intention now. thx